# Turn down volumetric smoke scale

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, volumetrics

I want to make some small smoke plumes using Cycles volumetric smoke. Think cigarette or car exhaust size. However, the default scale of smoke detail seems to be very large. Using default unit scale (1 unit = 1 meter), my smoke plumes have almost no detail at small sizes. I have to make them the size of buildings to have them look like I want. If I make the domain small, then I just get a tiny slice of low resolution.

Is there any way to adjust the whole scale down, or is this limited by voxel divisions? In that case, it ends up being easier to bake a giant oil well plume than a cigarette plume?

Comment: can you upload the file you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my results, although not tuned perfectly, I feel they are reasonable.
For me the trick is in setting the `Smoke High Resolution` and bumping up the divisions.

There is some other things in here like smoke texture, and other minor things for you to look at to fit, so I've included a blend file as well.

[image]

[image]